# Is NER suitable for selecting an entire sentence as an entity?

Tags: natural-language, named-entity-recognition

If I have a document with many paragraphs of text, would using a custom NER model be suitable to identify a sentence as a recognized entity? The desired sentences will be similar in semantic structure--but not similar enough to use RegEx!

Comment: NER models usually detects compound words at best not entire sentence. If we talk about sentence similarity, NER is not suitable approach.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)—what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I need to parse a fairly large document for sentences that convey certain meaning. This appears to be a classification problem, and I thought NER could be suitable because NER models can also identify spans as well as other entities.  I was curious if traditional entities could be expanded to capture broader ideas.